# Need to get video play pause and stop time in angular 2

Tags: angular, html5-video

am developing an application in angular 2, where I need to get the user last play, paused and stop time of a video, is there any video player is available to manipulate the video and get these details from Npm, if so please help me, sorry if this was a duplicated question

Comment: There is https://github.com/videogular/videogular2 but you can use any JavaScript video player and wrap it in an Angular component.

Comment: using that can I able t get the user Play, Pause and Stop time of a video

Comment: Please be more specific. Indicate exactly what you have done, providing code examples and what didn't work.

Comment: @AngularFrance am in requirement gathering phase, I have not yet started the development phase, I need to report to the client whether the Video Play, Pause and Stop time can be taken from the user video

Comment: I never asked anybody to do my client  work did I ?..